Can the app GUI & Form Designer look exactly the same in C++Builder Community Edition?
For example, I am trying to have it display colors in the Form Designer during the design process. Is this possible without running the compiler, or is this a limit of the designer?

Is there a way for these to be exactly the same?

VCL or FMX? The Form Designer should already be displaying the color you assign at design-time. Are you saying it doesn't?

for VCL. is there some setting i need to specify? i am using the debug layout.

at the moment it does not. only in the compiler.

Try this: Tools Options dialog, User Interface, Form designer, “Enable VCL Styles”

interestingly they are already checked. does this have to do with firemonkey? it says firemonkey doesn't support those features with the *

When I untick "Enable VCL styles", under "Form Designer", the designer follows settings of the form color.

Stating the obvious, but if you change a forms colour at run time (by assigning a colour to the color property) then it won't be the same in the form designer as when it runs...

@RogerCigol Stating the obvious, you apparently misunderstood the question. It was about design time settings and appearance.
